# Computer stops during boot sequence, boot-repair did not work

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Hello fellow ubuntu users,

I am using 20.04 on this computer. it was shutdown normally and next day did not complete boot sequence. I tried using a start up disk to do boot repair, the dump from that utility is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/StNQQcQFvK/

The following lines in the log on the URL above look suspicious to me - line #67 thru #73:

```
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd1.  Check your device.map.

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

An error occurred during the repair.

You can now reboot your computer.
```

Please let me know if you need more details, I will provide.

thanks for looking.

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI mode and not in old BIOS mode from old grub in MBR of sdb? Can you press escape & get grub menu. And then boot recovery mode? It looks like grub is correct, so error is after grub. Are all the UUIDs for the mounts of partitions in fstab correct?

Comment: hello, I am booting in UEFI mode, correct, using sda1. I tried booting into recovery mode once by holding shift down, it did not help. the last message to flash by before the sequence stops and i get to a fast blinking cursor is "/dev/sda2: clean, ....". I did not change fstab after the initial install. If needed i can copypaste contents of fstab here.

Comment: contents of fstab are in the log on the url above.

Comment: Use Escape key with UEFI and you have to press between UEFI/BIOS screen & when grub menu appears or often have to try several times. Shift key is for BIOS systems. What video card/chip do you have? What brand/model system?

Comment: Hey Oldfred, I was able to enter grub menu using the escape key as you explained above, and was able to enter recovery mode. I fixed dpkg to repair broken packages, there were some. after that i also dropped to shell and did a update/upgrade, the system did take all upgrades successfully. I also ran the update boot loader option. But after all of that, on reboot I am still in the same place. the last message that scrolls by is still the same - "/dev/sda2: clean, ....". Please help, and thanks!

Comment: If recovery mode works, you are able to boot, but have a graphic issue. What video card/chip and what version of Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: This computer has ubuntu 20.04, video chip is NVidia GEFORCE 210. this is a custom build, quiet old actually, amd athlon based cpu

Comment: after your previous comment, i got suspicious of the video card and replaced it with a radeon card. I do not see a change in behavior, with one difference -  now both monitors are showing the same sequence of events, instead of the one hooked on HDMI earlier.

Comment: I do not know AMD video, but with nVidia you used always use nomodeset to install & first boot. Now there is Safe Boot and the option to install the nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. Generally AMD is just supposed to work, but some old cards are not supported with newer AMD drivers, only Radeon driver.

Comment: latest boot repair log here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/v2vSsp4jsX/

Comment: If you are booting in UEFI mode, it looks correct. But the hard drive entry tries to boot an old grub BIOS boot entry and will not work.

Comment: So I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 on the system, using UEFI mode (same exact install as previous time), and it seems to be working fine. Would still like to know what caused this in the first place. Oldfred, thanks again for your prompt replies and helping with this.